# Error communicating with http://address:8777 [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: openstack

I am new to openstack. I have added openstack-ceilometer-api, openstack-ceilometer-central and openstack-ceilometer-collector on controller node, and added openstack-ceilometer-compute on compute node.

When I execute "ceilometer meter-list" I get the error

```
Error communicating with http://address:8777 [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

On the compute node I see the compute.log in /var/log/ceilometer

```
ERROR ceilometer.openstack.common.rpc.impl_qpid [-] Unable to connect to AMQP server: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Sleeping 60 seconds
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Error communicating with `http://adress:8777` [Errno 111] Connection
>   refused

means your ceilometer-api is not running

> ERROR ceilometer.openstack.common.rpc.impl_qpid [-] Unable to connect
>   to AMQP server: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Sleeping 60 seconds

means your AMQP(QPID) service is not running

go check qpid's log and try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the port is blocked by a firewall, or the server is actually listening on a different port. You'll have to open that port in the firewall probably.

Comment: I have disabled the iptables on both the nodes.

Comment: Is the server actually listening on that port? Is the server listening to the IP address you think it is?